# Adding new rows of information according to the range of rows set using user form

Tags: vba, excel, userform

Hi  I have an excel file that consist of 3 sizes of project (big, medium and small project sizes). I have already separated them according to their project sizes in just one excel sheet. However in the future, I would need to add in new projects according to the project sizes. I would need a code for a user form to run and add in the new information according to the project sizes. So far I only manage to create some codes. However it does not work as it would find any empty rows and fill in, which is not what i wanted. What i wanted is a code that would help to select based on the project sizes and insert new rows from there. For example the new project size is small thus, the project information will be inserted into the empty rows found in the small size project.
This is the code that I have so far.

```
    Private Sub CommandAddButton1_Click()

lastrow = Sheets("Programme Status Summary").Range("J").End(xlDown).Row

    Cells(lastrow + 1, "J").Value = TextBoxProjCode.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "E").Value = TextBoxProjName.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "C").Value = TextBoxSegment.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "F").Value = TextBoxSummary.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "G").Value = TextBoxAcc1.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "H").Value = TextBoxAcc2.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "I").Value = TextBoxProjM.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "K").Value = TextBoxCountry.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "L").Value = TextBoxRegulatory.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "M").Value = TextBoxRiskLvl.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "P").Value = TextBoxSchForecast.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "R").Value = TextBoxSchPar.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "S").Value = TextBoxImpact.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "T").Value = TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "U").Value = TextBoxCustRetail.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "V").Value = TextBoxOutsourcingImp.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "W").Value = TextBoxListImpt.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "X").Value = TextBoxKeyStatus.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "N").Value = TextBoxSchStart.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "O").Value = TextBoxSchEnd.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "Y").Value = TextBoxRagStatus.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "Z").Value = TextBoxRagCost.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "AA").Value = TextBoxRagBenefit.Text

Unload AddMedProjects

End Sub
```

I hope anyone could help me with this as i am not good at this. Thank you!

Comment: is the different project size defined in your worksheet? like as followed: `A1="Big Project", A50="Medium Project", A100="Small Project"` if so i would suggest to look at [.find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)  to define where to start searching for an empty row

Comment: No i do not define my project sizes. i created like a table for each of the project sizes with their respective columns. @DragonSamu

Comment: How do you select the size of the project? As far as I understood you have seperated the projects by seperate tables, so i.E. Column A to Z are small projects, AB to BB are medium sized and so on. This is how you could catch it, but you need to have a way to read if the project is small, medium or large and then just modifiy the targets of the text boxes.

Comment: Hi i didn't do it that way. i separate it according to rows. for example row 6 to row 100 is categorised as small size business and so on. @BlindSeer

Comment: Are there any text values to catch the size? I.E. Column AA has something like "small", "big", medium"? If so you could even spare some work and just add the lines at the end and sort this column.

Comment: I did a border like a table form for each project sizes based on rows. on top of each table, i would name it as big, small and medium projects. for example row 4 to row 66 i will create like a table form (input borders to it) on top of the table i would put the header which is the project size. the header of the sizes is on row 2 column E (small size), row 100 column E (medium size) and so on. @BlindSeer